# Can I use a local proxy mail server (using no username/password) to connect to a remote SMTP server (requiring username/password)?

Tags: email, smtp, email-server

The title is a bit wordy but I couldn't think of a way to make it more concise without losing some meaning.

**Context**

On a Windows machine I have an application which sends mail and can connect to an SMTP mail server, but due to a bug only it can only connect if it doesn't require a username/password. I can specify the following fields.

- SMTP Server Address
- SMTP Port
- Enable SSL/TLS

However I'd like this application to connect to a mail server that does require username/password authentication.

**Question**

Is there any software that would act as a proxy so that I could point the application to the local proxy, and have the proxy connect to the mail server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's perfectly possible.

The function you are looking for is normally called smarthost or relayhost

Postfix and sendmail both support this feature.

Instructions for setting up sendmail [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204299/centos-sendmail-smtp-smarthost-with-authentication) and postfix [here](https://stafwag.github.io/blog/blog/2018/03/04/postfix-smarthost-with-authentication/)

For the best security you probably want to make sure you limit the proxy mail server to only accept unauthenticated mail submission from your application server machine

Comment: Those look ideal, thanks! Do you know if they're Linux only? I was able to discover E-mail relay which works on Windows and once I used the Gmail example as a template, it worked a charm. http://emailrelay.sourceforge.net/index.html#userguide_md_Google_mail

Comment: Postfix is unix only iirc and to be honest I'd avoid sendmail as it's a pig to configure. It's pretty easy to set up postfix on a raspberry pi if needed.