# How to use NGINX as legacy SMTP proxy to new SMTP system?

Tags: nginx, proxy, smtp, smtp-auth

We have some very old radio equipment in the field which uses SMTP to notify us of failures.  Unfortunately this equipment does not support modern SMTP authentication methods (SSL, etc), and can only send PLAIN auth method.

(It is not an option to upgrade the devices to use modern auth. methods)

I found [this article](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/mail-proxy/mail-proxy/) on configuring NGINX as a SMTP proxy.

But I need to do the following, which the article didn't explain fully:

1. Accept incoming SMTP connections from legacy equipment on Port 25.
2. Filter incoming connections by IP address (we would manually maintain a list of permitted IPs) and only allow those on the list.
3. (optional) validate incoming SMTP connection PLAIN authentication (username/password)
4. Connect to the modern SMTP server using modern authentication method (SSL), using a different username and password (these credentials would be hard coded in the NGINX config file, as all notifications get sent from the same address).
5. discard the sender's "FROM" command and inject our own, to match the user in #4.
6. discard the sender's "TO" command and inject our own (all notifications go to the same destination address)
7. Pass the "DATA" command through to the modern server unchanged.

Hopefully this makes sense. Basically we are injecting our own authentication so that the modern server accepts the connection regardless of the sending server's authentication method, and using IP addresses to block bots and spammers.

Thanks for any advice.  This may be too much to ask of NGINX and may require a custom solution (i.e. Python, Node, etc).  Any suggestions welcome.

I also found [this SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1003500/can-i-use-a-local-proxy-mail-server-using-no-username-password-to-connect-to-a) which explains this process using sendmail and postfix.  But I was still curious if it could be done solely with NGINX.

Comment: Nginx is a proxy. It isn't going to modify anything.

Comment: @paul thanks, wasn't sure if Nginx had the capability to mangle traffic as it passed through.

Answer (score 1):

you will find better result by looking for "SMTP relay" although it's like a proxy.

I was not aware NGINX had mail capabilities. NGINX is a well known web server but I am not sure twisting it to support mail is their best idea (purely unjustified argument !)

I recommend simpler solutions:

- https://github.com/decke/smtprelay
- https://github.com/wiggin77/mailrelay

Comment: Thanks @exeral, those two look promising, especially mailrelay, which specifically states that it can interoperate between PLAIN and SSL authentication modes.  I think this may solve the problem quite handily.

Comment: Nginx can proxy mail as long as the mail module is included, which it usually is.